# How to write a java function in Spring data derivative

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Right now I write the function to get the number of working days myself. Instead of course it is much better to make use of Spring data and let the database make the calculation.

So how could I write the second function in Spring data.

It should be something like. Count by Date Distinct group by date  from WorkingDay . A workingDayObject can occur more than once per day if somebody worked on different projects . That's way I use a hashset in my function to get just the days.

```
private double calculateOvertimeHours(WorkingMonth month) 
{   
    double workedHours = Util.convertTimeToDoubleDecimal(month.getWorkedHours());

    //Here I use a Spring data method as you can see
    List<WorkingDay> lstWorkingDays = workingDayDao.findByWorkingMonthOrderByDateAsc(month);        

    return workedHours - calcNumberWorkDays(lstWorkingDays) * 8;
}

private int calcNumberWorkDays(List<WorkingDay> lstWorkingDays)
{
    Set<Integer> hashSetDays = new HashSet<Integer>(); 
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

    for(WorkingDay workingDay :  lstWorkingDays)
    {
        cal.setTime(workingDay.getDate());
        hashSetDays.add(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    }

    return hashSetDays.size();
}
```

Comment: Don't... Just write a query that does this. The Spring Data query methods are for simple use cases, for evertyhting else just write a query.

Comment: It's always bad idea to make database do any calculation. If you still wanting triggers and stored procedures may help you. But left's you code as it is, it's correct to hold business logic in Java.

Comment: The query should be not so complicated. I have a list of WorkingDays. Every workingDay has a date. I just want to count distinct Workingdays based on date. How would the query look in that case

Comment: That is the SQL query :  Select  count(date) as count,date from (SELECT * FROM workingday where workingMonth_id=61) as t group by date

Comment: No my query is even more complicated. It is like that .  Select count(*) from (Select distinct count(date) as number,date from (SELECT * FROM exantastime.workingday where workingMonth_id=61) as t group by date) as xx

Comment: You can plop your SQL query in a `@Query` annotation on a method of a repository or in a `@Formula` annotation on an entity (that's Hibernate only I think). Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: yeah I know. But when using that you have problems with subselects. I think JPQL has limitations on that. In normal SQL though subselects are perfectly fine.